# How to remove offset in datetime

Tags: flutter

i would like some help on this i actually use **TZDateTime** and also with specific location now i would to remove the end of the result like .123436+100 from it

```
final dateTime = TZDateTime.now(getLocation(box.read(timezone)));
```

the result always i get is something like this

```
 2022-04-20 17:42:05.032173+1000
```

but i want is only like this

```
2022-04-20 17:42:05
```

how can i remove that actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `TZDateTime` before but I think it's the same as `DateTime`. By using `DateFormat` from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) you can format the string as you want.

ps1: in case `TZDateTime` cant parse directly, you can turn it to string and pass to `DateTime.parse`.
ps2: this answer of mine is an idea and has not been tested correctly, sorry if it didn't help you.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var time = DateTime.parse('2022-04-20 17:42:05.032173+1000');
  var fm = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
  print(fm.format(time)); // -> 2022-04-20 07:42:05
}
```

[image]

Comment: really thanks it works, Though its new to me to use DateFormat i didnt know this one exist really thanks i solve my problem rn.